# ajax updating a class element

Tags: php, jquery

I have a shopping cart with a list of items in the cart array. When one is removed, it updates the cart through ajax, however the item number in the array, for each shopping cart item, will not update unless page is refreshed.

```
<input class="remove_cart_id" type="hidden" value="'.$i.'" />
```

The $i indicates the number in the array. If an item is removed, this could effect the order of the array, so I want to update $i for each class.

Rather than having to output the entire cart contents, is there an easy way to just update an element for each class. It could be done quite easily, with $i = 0, and i++ for each item in the shopping cart array.

UPDATE:

```
$('.remove_cart_item').click(function(){
$(this).parent().stop(true, true).fadeOut();
var pid = $('.remove_cart_id', this).val();
$.ajax({        
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : 'ajax/remove-cart.php',
    data    : 'pid='+pid,
    success : function(data) {
        $('#cart_quantity').html(data);
    }
});
// update cart array
var i = 0; 
$('.remove_cart_id').each(function(){ 
    $(this).val(i); 
    i++; 
};
```

});

I am using this code now, but there seems to be some sort of bug with the each function, as the code stopped working.

Comment: that doesn't sound like the right approach. Perhaps your value of this input should be a referenced id of the item and not its position in the index since that could introduce a disconnect, as you have come to see.

Answer (score 0):

To change values based on the class, try

```
$(".classname").each(function() {
   $(this).val('change');
});
```

Class generally applies to multiple elements being group together. If you have another element in the same class, the value change will be applied for it as well.

Comment: so on client side I want to update these values on click.
So it would be something like

     `$i = 0;
     foreach('.remove_cart_id.) {
     $(this).val() = $i;
     $i++
     }`
Does that make sense? Not sure how to code that properly in jquery, or if it would work.

Comment: I would go with 
    var i = 0;
    $('.remove_cart_id').each(function(){
     $(this).val(i); i++;
    }

Javascript does not use '$'. You may be confusing it with PHP. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to re-index the values

```
function reindexCart(){
  var count = 0;
  $('.remove_cart_id').each(){
    $(this).val(count);
    count++;
  }
}
```

Or, do you need to decrement the value?

Comment: I just need to re-number the elements based on their order in the cart.

Comment: then call above provided reindexCart() function after removing item. Hope this will solve you problem